# Используя gulp (wiredep + gulp-pug) время от времени ловлю ошибку

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm, browsersync

Начал использовать GULP. Создал вот такой конфиг:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var notify = require("gulp-notify");
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browserSync = require("browser-sync");
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var svgstore = require('gulp-svgstore');
var svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var bsConfig = require("gulp-bootstrap-configurator");
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var gulpPugBeautify = require('gulp-pug-beautify');

// IMAGES
gulp.task('img', () =>
    gulp.src('app/img/originals/*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img'))
);

// SVG
gulp.task('svg', ['img'], function() {
    return gulp
        .src('app/img/originals/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgmin())
        .pipe(svgstore())
        .pipe(rename({ basename: 'sprite' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img/'))
        .pipe(notify('Done SVG Convert!'));
});

// STYLES
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expand' }).on("error", notify.onError()))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'));
});

// BUILD
gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

});

// BOWER
gulp.task('bower', function() {
    gulp.src('./app/*.html')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: "app/bower_components"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});

// BROWSER SYNC
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        host: 'site1.domain.dev',
        port: 3060,
        open: false,
        notify: false,
        ghost: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: './app'
        },
        notify: false,
        browser: "google chrome"
    });
});

gulp.task('bootstrap', ['make-bootstrap-js', 'make-bootstrap-css']);

gulp.task('make-bootstrap-js', function() {
    return gulp.src("./bt-config.json")
        .pipe(bsConfig.js({
            compress: false,
            bower: false,
            name: 'bootstrap.min.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/js/"));
    // It will create compressed `my.js` in directory `assets`.
});

gulp.task('make-bootstrap-css', function() {
    return gulp.src("./bt-config.json")
        .pipe(bsConfig.css({
            compress: false,
            bower: false,
            name: 'bootstrap.min.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/css/"));
    // It will create `bootstrap.css` in directory `assets`. 
});

// PUG
gulp.task('views', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/views/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({ pretty: true }).on("error", notify.onError()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/views/**/*.pug', ['views']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', ['bower']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/css/**/*.scss', ['sass'], browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/css/**/*.scss', browserSync.reload);
});
```

При работе с *.pug часто ловлю ошибку вот такого содержания:

```
events.js:160
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
    at fromObject (buffer.js:262:9)
    at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:101:10)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:80:17)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (/Volumes/My Passport/Development/rvdrm/node_modules/wiredep/wiredep.js:136:23)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Volumes/My Passport/Development/rvdrm/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:182:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Volumes/My Passport/Development/rvdrm/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:170:83)
    at doWrite (/Volumes/My Passport/Development/rvdrm/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:406:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Volumes/My Passport/Development/rvdrm/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:395:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Volumes/My Passport/Development/rvdrm/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:322:11)
    at write (/Volumes/My Passport/Development/rvdrm/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?